# does Trichloroacetic acid remove fats from milk

Tags: proteins, milk

I am trying to detect melamine in milk. As a part of preprocessing, I add 200 ul of TCA to 1 mL milk,and after filtration I get a clear solution. Does the filtrate contain fat. I feel I am having interference from fat even after extraction.

Comment: It is likely that the fats are present in both the filtrate and the ppt. because as far as I am aware this test does not distinguish fats/ lipids into micro or macromolecules...You find the macromolecules in the ppt. But the micro in the filtrate so yes, there is a chance of interference as you have concluded.